# Trigger selectize load method programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Again simple question on [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md).

I have an independent user interface element (let's refer to it as **input A**) and a selectize element.
Selectize element is defined as follows:

```
var test = $('#my_selectize').selectize({
    // ....
    load: function(query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/remote_url/',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {q: query},
                error: function() { callback(); },
                success: function(res) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(res.f));
                }
            });
        }
    })[0].selectize;
```

Now, I want the load method to be triggered everytime the user edits input A.
To do this, I tried the following according to [the doc](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/events.md):

```
$('#input_A').on('change', function(){
        test.trigger('load');}
```

And nothing happens. Any ideas? Is it possible whatsoever ?

Comment: Hi you can inspire from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dsqwared/6zyums3d/13/) :  $('#select').trigger( "load" );

Comment: I have noticed that .trigger('load') does not trigger the function specified in "load" option, but, if you have specified an onLoad function you will notice that it is triggered. I have the same issue btw, still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("#inputA").change(function (e) {
         test.onSearchChange($(this).val()); //test = $('#my_selectize')[0].selectize;
 });
```

There is a method (onSearchChange) which triggers the "load" event in Selectize source code. We can use this method to trigger load method manually at code behind.

Comment: How does this line of code solves the problem? Better explain a bit?

Comment: @cytsunny i  edited my answer. Do you need more explantation?

Comment: This method is not present in the documentation. It looks like an internal function. It did not solve a similar problem I had.

Comment: Yes it (onSearchChange)  is a private method of selectize. There is no public method in the documentation to  trigger searching from code behind js. So i resolved my problem by this way and it works fine for me.   $("#theinput")[0].selectize.onSearchChange("blabla");

Comment: I find this usefull and I think the documentation should have it.!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I hope it helps someone.

```
const selectize = elem.selectize({
  //...
  onLoad: () => {
    //if you need to refresh list after changes
    elem[0].selectize.refreshOptions();
  }
});
    
otherElem.change(() => {
  const { selectize } = elem[0];
  const value = elem.find("input").val(); //here I just get selectize input value
    
  delete selectizeElem.loadedSearches[value];
  selectize.onSearchChange(value);
});
```